Using OBS with Virtual Camera on Debian Bookworm
I just installed OBS on Debian Bookworm and two things became apparent immediately:

"Screen Capture" only outputs a black screen.
There is no button under "Controls" for starting the virtual camera.

How can OBS be made usable?



OBS: Install the package obs-studio.


# apt install obs-studio


PipeWire: Install the package pipewire from the backports. (This enables screeen capturing.)


Open your sources.list file with the following command:
# apt edit-sources
You may need to choose your preferred text editor. (nano is recommended for new users.)
If it doesn't already exist, append the following line to the file:
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports main contrib non-free
Save and exit the file. (CTRL+X in nano)
Update APT's cache to include the backports in the list of available packages:
# apt update
Note that you don't have to repeat all of the above the next time you want to install a package from the backports.
Install the package pipewire from the backports:
# apt install -t bookworm-backports pipewire


v4l2loopback: Install the package v4l2loopback-dkms. (This enables the virtual camera.)


# apt install v4l2loopback-dkms

